# Get public content from Instagram on behalf of User

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

Now that Instagram have changed there policy and they have disabled the below capabilities:

- Follower List - to read the list of followers and followed-by users
  Relationships - to follow and unfollow accounts on a user’s behalf
  Commenting on Public Content
- to post and delete comments on a
  user’s behalf on public media Likes
- to like and unlike media on a
  user’s behalf Subscriptions
- to receive notifications when media is
  posted Users Information
- to search for and view users' public
  content Some information on Public Content returned through hashtag
  and location search
- Name, Bio, Comments, Commenters, Follower
  Count, Following Count, Post Count, and Profile Picture

So now is there a way to search user and get there public content?

I have seached on https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/ but not able to found the replacement.

Comment: Have you checked this link [change log](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/)

Comment: yes, they have disabled the GET /users/{user-id}
GET /users/{user-id}/media/recent end points which i have used.

Answer (score 3):

After the recent change, it is only allowed to get information on **Instagram Business Accounts** and one must use Facebook's graph API for that.

One should also have an **Instagram Business Account** to do so. 
Check out this guide from Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started

As to Facebook Graph API calls, below are a few examples:

*Get ID of Facebook pages (You will need that to get own Instagram Business  Account ID)*

```
/me/accounts
```

*Get **your own** Instagram Business Account ID*

```
FACEBOOK_Page_ID?fields=instagram_business_account
```

*Get basic account information for **any** Instagram business account by username (I have used "stonebrewing" as an example)*

```
Your_Instagram_Business_Account_ID?fields=business_discovery.username(stonebrewing){
    biography,website,username,followers_count,media_count
    }
```

*Get a list of posts and some data for **any** Instagram Business Account*

```
Your_Instagram_Business_Account_ID?fields=business_discovery.username(stonebrewing)
{media{id,comments_count,like_count,media_type, media_url, caption, owner}}
```

Comment: Isn't it required to have business account for each user. Earlier we have one app created in Instagram and after that using the access token of that app, we were able to search the public content of other users. But now i am not able to find the way to do that.

Comment: No, it isn't. Having just one business account access token should be enough to collect a limited amount of data for any other instagram business account.